# redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -3 connecting to redis:6379. Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: django, redis, celery

redis.service is active and I can connect to redis-cli but in Django I got the issue when Celery try to get access to redis:6379 (as I understand).

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get('REDISCLOUD_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0')
CACHEOPS_REDIS = os.environ.get('CACHEOPS_REDIS', 'redis://localhost:6379/9')

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_lock.django_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
            'DB': 3,
        }
    }
}
```

It happened after I reinstalled Ubuntu. Before was ok.

Comment: Does your redis server listens to `6379`? Is there and `bind_address` set in the redis config?

Comment: resolved. actually I don't know how. I've installed redis docker container , reboot and it works!